# How to make this array flat?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array,  some elements are single string, final element is comma seperated string

```
Array (
    [0] => text 
    [1] => text 
    [2] => text
    [3] => text1, text2, text3
 )
```

I want to join all elements into one comma seperated string. Neither explode nor join could manage this. How can I get a result like this:

```
array(text, text, text, text1, text2, text3)
```

Comment: So do you want to have a string or an array as the result? You talk about a string, but the example result you give is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use implode:

```
implode(",", $array);
```

Answer (score 2):

implode it and then explode

```
$array = explode(',', implode(',', $array));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$aNew = array(implode(', ', $aTest));
```

Also see [this](http://ideone.com/kHDcn) or [this](http://ideone.com/yWUZj) example.